# Is it possible to convert Laravel 5.5 project into laravel 5.4 without any harm to that project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I am facing a problem with my hosting server where php 5.6 has been installed which can't be upgrade to php 7. But my project has been completed in laravel 5.5 which need php 7 to run. Is there any solution to switch laravel 5.5 to laravel 5.4

Comment: i thing replace resource,app,route and asset folder

Comment: Only this? are you sure?

Comment: yes,try once.get backup your whole project

Comment: copy paste you composer.json code and update composer

Comment: Set composer.json to Laravel version 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is no easy way to do that. If application is using Laravel 5.5 features some parts of it won't work and you might waste a lot of time to finding and fixing those issues.

In my opinion much cheaper way would be changing hosting and in fact it would me more reasonable to use PHP 7.x than 5.6 in 2017/2018. If you look at [PHP versions](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) you will see, that for 5.6 only security fixes are applied at the moment

Comment: Totaly agree with the answer. Another workaround might be to create a docker with PHP 7 inside the machine that you get from the hosting company.

Comment: Good answers and suggestions. I've expierenced that webhosters I've contacted about changing the php version are 9/10 times free of charge. Make sure when they are about to change the php version the latest version is ready on the server to save you from some downtime. Docker is awesome too.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all guys.